# How do I remotely connect to Linux installed on an Android phone from Windows 10 PC both at the same network? I tried Putty, RDP, SSH, VNC, and XRDP

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop, android, vnc

i tried putty, RDP, ssh, VNC, XRDP, but no success. Both the win-PC and phone are on same local network i can connect to linux via VNC from mobile phone using 127.0.0.1:xxxx , when i run the ifconfig or localhost -I on linux terminal in it shows the IP which is same as my mobile phone IP i.e.  192.xxx.x.x. Is there any way i can connect to linux ( via RDP , PUtty , VNC etc ) from my PC using the same IP.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried appending the same port number (:xxxx) that you use for the localhost connection? (e.g. 192.168.1.x:5900)

Answer (score 1):

An IP address is not enough to connect to a device.  There has to be a server on the Linux device to accept incoming connections.

You didnt list what kind on Linux you are using, which would help greatly.  Assuming your Linux is Debian based, the following should allow SSH to work.  However, if it is based off a non-Aptitude based Linux, you should be able to easily adapt the following to your needs.

In order to install SSH, you can run the following command to install the Open SSH server:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Enter your password and accept any prompts.  Once the install is finished, you need to start the server.  You can use the following command:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

From Windows, run Putty and SSH nto your Ubuntu machine with the following command:

```
ssh <insert name or IP here>
```

The first time you SSH into a machine, you will be prompted and asked if you trust the machine.  Accept and you will be remotely connected to your Ubuntu machine.

At this point you can type in any commands you want.